# apply a function to a dataframe column (datetime.date)

Tags: python, pandas

I Have the following code

```
 def func (datas):

                giorno=calendar.day_name[int(datas.day)]
                mese=calendar.month_name[int(datas.month)]
                day = getattr(result,'beta')
                day=getattr(day,'%s'%(giorno))
                month= getattr(result,'beta')
                month=getattr(month,'%s'%(mese))
                intercept=result.beta.intercept
                d = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
                holiday_map = dict(cal.holidays(d.year))  
                holiday_=holiday_map.get(d, '?')
                holiday= getattr(result,'beta')
                holiday=getattr(holiday,holiday_)
                return int(intercept)+int(month)+int(day)+int(holiday)
```

I'm trying to apply this formula on a dataframe column 'Days' (datetime.date  type):

```
df_reg['regression']=df_reg['days'].map(lambda datas: data(datas))
```

but I get the following error:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in __getitem__(self, i)
     73 
     74     def __getitem__(self, i):
---> 75         funcs = self._days[i]
     76         if isinstance(i, slice):
     77             return [f(self.format) for f in funcs]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include all of the `import`s and any other information necessary to execute this code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi could yo post few raw data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `datas.day` in the first line. It is out of range.

The valid values are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]